# Codeigniter: Know AI ID of query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

When a user create an item, on my controller i need to send 2 SQL Query.
The first is easy to do:

```
$data = array(
  'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
  'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
);
$this->item_model->insertItem($data);
```

But on my second query, i need to recover, to find the ID of the query showing just before.

For example:

```
$data = array(
  'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
  'item_id' => ????,
);
$this->item_model->insertItem($data);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching [the last inserted ID](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id) of variable $item_id in the same transaction of your controller, you can get the ID of record in the same session as follows:

```php
$item_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's work fine. I already see this answer on another post but i try to put it on model.. Thanks